# Solve a system of coupled differential equations in Python

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations, linear-system

I have a system of two coupled differential equations, one is a third-order and the second is second-order. I am looking for a way to solve it in Python.

I would be extremely grateful for any advice on how can I do that or simplify this set of equations that define a boundary value problem :

[image]

Pr is just a constant (Prandtl number)

Thank you for your help,

N.B : This question is not related to any previous topic, this set of equation may need a simplification that I don't see. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving coupled differential equations in Python, 2nd order](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34304/solving-coupled-differential-equations-in-python-2nd-order)

Comment: @BillGreene Thank you for your reply : unfortunately, I have already seen this conversation but it's not the same kind of simplification that is needed... I think I can apply a shooting method algorithm on this type of problem but I don't see how to simplify it. Thank you again.

Comment: So this is a boundary value rather than an initial value problem? In any case, you should edit your question to include the boundary or initial conditions. What do you mean by "may need a simplification that I don't see"? Converting higher order ODE to first order form is something that has been discussed widely. I strongly suggest you do not try to implement your own algorithm for solving this system unless there is some feature that is not evident from your post.

Comment: @BillGreene Yes it is a Boundary value problem : I have updated my post in order to clarify the boundary conditions. I mean that maybe I need a transformation to reduce the order of each equation in order to simplify it. In fact I used to solve linear BVP by a shooting method algorithm so I have already done it before but this particular system doesn't allow me to apply the shooting method so I am a little bit lost in order to find a strategy to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Probably you can solve this problem by shooting, should not be too hard.

Comment: When you say you want to simplify the equations, what do you mean?  Are you asking how to turn it into a system of first order equations so that you can use a shooting method?

Comment: @KyleMandli Yes it is exactly what I am trying to do : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: The $x$ in the first equation, is that the independent variable or just a multiplication sign? What is a typical range for values for Pr? (You could use mathjax here.)

Comment: Hello again @LutzLehmann : the x is just the multiplication sign. The Pr has to be superior than one so I attend to do a simulation with Pr varying between 1 and 10. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no higher magic necessary, just transcribe into the canonical first-order system, encode the boundary conditions, make a reasonable initial guess of the solution shape and call the BVP solver

```python
Pr = 5

def odesys(t,u):
    F,dF,ddF,θ,dθ = u
    return [dF, ddF, θ-0.25/Pr*(2*dF*dF-3*F*ddF), dθ, 0.75*F*dθ]

def bcs(u0,u1): return [u0[0], u0[1], u1[2]-1, u0[3]-1, u1[3]]

x = np.linspace(0,1,4)
u = [0.5*x*x, x, 0*x+1, 1-x, 0*x-1]

res = solve_bvp(odesys,bcs,x,u, tol=1e-5)
print(res.message)
```

Then plotting the solution gives

[image]

Comment: Once again you allowed me to solve a system of differential equations...  In fact I used to solve BVP with my own code that works fine with simple cases but for this one I had some problems with the boundary conditions... I have to work on that for the future : Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

What does differentiating the first equation once to give $\theta'$ and twice for $\theta''$ and plugging into the second equation to give a single equation for $F$ give? Seems like solving a single equation for $F$ might be your best approach (or vice versa).

Comment: Thank you for your answer : I tried this option but it ended with a differential equation of order 5 and I don't have the required number of boundary values in order to solve it.

Comment: Seems like you have plenty of BCs, but some of them will end up being of mixed type.